# nginx cannot resolve local hostname

Tags: nginx, docker

I am trying to use nginx as a proxy for load balancing 2 servers. 
I don't know the best practices here, but this is the scenario:

- official.domain.com (the hostname resolve the nginx ip)
- app1.domain.com (the server number one of the app)
- app2.domain.com (the server number two of the app)

Since only the official domain will be public, the others two are "private", I don't want a user or a search engine will see these domains so I was thinking of modifying the `/etc/hosts` and force the 2 ips on the two hostnames. I did it on the nginx container and on the host too, but without success. Nginx is telling me that it cannot resolves app1.domain.com

I know that if I create a public hostname on the domain for app1 and app2 this should work, but I want to tell nginx to resolve locally these domain.

Edit
the output of `getent hosts app1.domain.com` or on `app2.domain.com` either on the container or the hosts is the same. With the correct ip. Both are resolving correctly now, but just because I add the ip on the public domain but now I have `Bad Gateway`

Comment: Can you share the output of `getent hosts app1.domain.com` from the host and from inside the container?

Also share contents of your `/etc/hosts` file

Comment: @RichardSmith if I put the ip, how the IIS bindings should work?

Comment: @kn330 I have updated the original question

Comment: Both are resolving correctly now, but just because I add the ip on the public domain but now I have `Bad Gateway`

Comment: If the machines are in the same network i.e. you are able to access the application machine from the nginx machine via its private IP address then you can update the A Records to private IPs of the machine.

Regarding `Bad Gateway` error, you must check your application logs.

Comment: @kn330 no they are not. they are differente machine in different place, accesible only via public network.
I resolve the bad gateway adding the binding to the iiss app1 and app2, with the ip. But I don't think is this the right way .Should the proxy, pass with the hostname not the ip?

Comment: @RichardSmith and for the other app2?

Comment: @RichardSmith maybe I don't get it, but how this is goingo to work with the round robin? If I have 2 upstreams one for every app/server, and can define only one upstream on the proxypass?